# From Chrome, I have a POST header used by JQuery API... How do I reproduce it?

Tags: jquery, post

I am trying to reproduce the JQuery POST request that has the following header (found using Google Chrome Developer Tools):

```
Remote Address:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Request URL:http://.../query
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:11
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:ARRAffinity=blahblah
Host:www.XXX.XXX
Origin:http://www.XXX.XXX
Referer:http://www.XXX.XXX/query
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
message:mymessage
```

I am trying to automate queries to that server using a program such as Java, C++ or anything basically that would let me automate this...

Anybody has any suggestions? I am not very familiar with JQuery...

Comment: Um... you have Request URL, header values, etc, you can just re-produce the POST call. Read jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you have found these data in Chrome Developer Tools, sure,  to reproduce the call is very simple.

**Step 1**, find the request in Chrome Developer Tools

**Step 2**, right click it, you'll see

[image]

**Step 3**, click **Copy as cURL**, then paste in any terminal that contains [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) command

I think it's the simplest way to reproduce a request.